# How to disable button depending on the length of input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make a simple quiz app in ReactJS. I created carousel cards. When the user answers the question, he will press the next button and a new question will appear.

I would like to prevent pressing the next button before writing any value in the text input.

I tried to achieve this with `event.target.value.length` property on the `onChange` event. It works on the first question properly. However, for the next questions, I need to fill in the text input and then remove it to be able to disable the next button.

So, the user cannot pass the first question without filling in the first input. But, he can pass the next questions with empty inputs.

Here is my functional component:

```
const [submitButton, enableSubmitButton] = useState({
        'isEnabled': false
      });

const handleChange = (event) => {
      if (event.target.value.length > 0) {
          enableSubmitButton({ 'isEnabled': true });
      } else {
          enableSubmitButton({ 'isEnabled': false });
      }
}

return (
     <React.Fragment>
         <Row>
           {posts.map((post) => (
                  <CardLayout key={ post.id } content={
                       <Label for={ 'question_' + post.id }>
                                  { post.question + ' ='}
                       </Label>
                       <Input id={ 'question_' + post.id } 
                              name={ 'question_' + post.id } 
                              onChange={ handleChange } />
                  } />
            ))}
          </Row>
          <Row>
               <Button type="submit" 
                       onClick={ next } 
                       disabled={ !submitButton.isEnabled }>
                       Next
                </Button>
          </Row>
     </React.Fragment>
)
```

How can I achieve to disable the next button depending on the length of all of the inputs values?

[image]

Comment: Have you debugged into the handleChange function? Does it receive the inserted value at all? Maybe have a look at the [forms docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). They use a reference as value attribute. You don't. Maybe that is a trace for you

Comment: @bastianowicz Yes it does. I get the inserted value with ```event.target.value``` in the handleChange function.

Comment: It might be a problem that you are mapping multiple posts that all use the same state. Since I don't see the posts I can only guess. Maybe the multiple posts overwrite each other and your button keeps its state.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the problem correctly, but here is my solution for the problem.

What I see as a problem is that you are disabling the button if the length is bigger than 0. Instead, you should check if it's smaller. So we need to change the logic to:

```js
const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true);

const handleChange = (event) => {
    setIsDisabled(event.target.value.length <= 0) // will set isdisabled to true if there is no input
}
```

jsx:

```js
 <React.Fragment>
         <Row>
           {posts.map((post) => (
                  <CardLayout key={ post.id } content={
                       <Label for={ 'question_' + post.id }>
                                  { post.question + ' ='}
                       </Label>
                       <Input id={ 'question_' + post.id } 
                              name={ 'question_' + post.id } 
                              onChange={ handleChange } />
                  } />
            ))}
          </Row>
          <Row>
               <Button type="submit" 
                       onClick={ next } 
                       disabled={isDisabled}>
                       Next
                </Button>
          </Row>
     </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Thank you @em_code. I arranged my codes. However, the result is the same. I attached a screen record to my question to make it more understandable.

Comment: Seems like you need to listen for changes in the posts array to update your state accordingly. You can try to set the state to true whenever content changes, that way the button will always be disabled on the first render: ``useEffect(() => {
    setIsDisabled(true)
  }, [posts])``